# bash grep string from text and send an email

Tags: linux, bash, text

I have a text file like below (file.txt):

```
name1 1235 56321
name2 76721 90320
name3 7781 324389
```

I want to use bash to read the file.txt and send email to name1@gmail.com , name2@gmail.com , name3@gmail.com

I tried for loop in file but don't know how to just grep the first column in text
e.g.

```
for (i in file.txt){
    mailx {print $1}@gmail.com 
}
```

is there any way that i can do for loop in finding all first column in a text file using bash and send the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `grep` (AKA search) for anything. You just need all the file contents, just select the first column:

```
for name in $(cut -f1 -d' ' file.txt)
do
    mailx "${name}@gmail.com"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cut` utility can help you out.  Also, your syntax is all wrong

```
for i in $(cut -f 1 -d " " file.txt)
do
    mailx $i@gmail.com 
done
```

TBH, you also probably want to generate some sort of predefined message, and feed that into mailx so it doesn't go into the prompt to type message, etc.